# JQuery : How to force the click of s specific item of a radiobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a page which contains a radio box , and where , items are identified by their diffrent numric ids ; i'm recupering the id of the item that should be clicked from another job , and i wanna force the click of that specific item :

*This is my HTML page :*

```
<div id="radioCategories" class="select-list__content toggle-box" id="toggle-list-categories">
    <label class="checkbox base-bloc" data-match-for="categoriemissionfreelancer">
      <input class="filtres" name="categorieFiltre" type="radio" id="1">
      <span class="check"></span>
      <span class="checkbox-title" data-match-forcontent="name"></span>
      <span>(<span data-match-forcontent="nbMission"></span>)</span>
    </label>


    <label class="checkbox base-bloc" data-match-for="categoriemissionfreelancer">
      <input class="filtres" name="categorieFiltre" type="radio" id="2">
      <span class="check"></span>
      <span class="checkbox-title" data-match-forcontent="name"></span>
      <span>(<span data-match-forcontent="nbMission"></span>)</span>
    </label>


    <label class="checkbox base-bloc" data-match-for="categoriemissionfreelancer">
      <input class="filtres" name="categorieFiltre" type="radio" id="3">
      <span class="check"></span>
      <span class="checkbox-title" data-match-forcontent="name"></span>
      <span>(<span data-match-forcontent="nbMission"></span>)</span>
    </label>


</div>
```

As you can see , i have the labels (itmes ) with the ids : 1,2,3

i have a function which is loadin dynamically the id which must be checked :

```
if (GetParams("cat_id")) {
  var id_cat = GetParams("cat_id");  // can be 1 or 2 or 3
}
```

i wann develop a function **which catch that "id_cat" and force the click (the event & the appearence ) on the item** of the specific id received

*so i started 
 by that :*

```
checkSelectedCategory: function(id_cat) {
  if (id) {
    $("#radioCategories input:radio").attr(id, id_cat).click(function() {
      alert("clicked");
    });
    $("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");

  }
}
```

But it didn't work , **any suggestions ?**

Comment: Based on the id_cat you want to get checked the radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove "checkSelectedCategory" function and add following code in if condition.

```
if (GetParams("cat_id")) {
  var id_cat = GetParams("cat_id");  // can be 1 or 2 or 3
  var _this = $("#"+id_cat);
  _this.prop("checked", true);
  _this.trigger("click");
}
```

Please check below snippet. Whichever value will be entered from 1,2,3 that radio button will be checked and click event also trigger on it onchange event of input type="text".

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dynamic_cat").on('change',function(){
    var id_cat = $(this).val();
    if (id_cat) {
      var _this = $("#"+id_cat);
      _this.prop("checked", true);
      _this.trigger("click");
    }
  });
  $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox" id="dynamic_cat" value=""/><br/>

<div id="radioCategories" class="select-list__content toggle-box" id="toggle-list-categories">
  <label class="checkbox base-bloc" data-match-for="categoriemissionfreelancer">
    <input class="filtres" name="categorieFiltre" type="radio" id="1">
    <span class="check"></span>
    <span class="checkbox-title" data-match-forcontent="name"></span>
    <span>(<span data-match-forcontent="nbMission"></span>)</span>
  </label>


  <label class="checkbox base-bloc" data-match-for="categoriemissionfreelancer">
    <input class="filtres" name="categorieFiltre" type="radio" id="2">
    <span class="check"></span>
    <span class="checkbox-title" data-match-forcontent="name"></span>
    <span>(<span data-match-forcontent="nbMission"></span>)</span>
  </label>


  <label class="checkbox base-bloc" data-match-for="categoriemissionfreelancer">
    <input class="filtres" name="categorieFiltre" type="radio" id="3">
    <span class="check"></span>
    <span class="checkbox-title" data-match-forcontent="name"></span>
    <span>(<span data-match-forcontent="nbMission"></span>)</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @firasKoubaa please chek my updated answer and also check snippet.

Answer (score 2):

attach the event on radio buttons like this

```
$("#radioCategories input[type='radio']").click(function() {
                        alert("clicked");
                    });
```

then in the checkSelectedCategory method trigger the event like this

```
checkSelectedCategory:function (id_cat) {
            if (id_cat){

                $("input#"+id_cat).trigger("click");

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need to click it? Or just select it with JS?

```js
var id_cat = 2;
var id     = '#' + id_cat;

// Simply select it.
$( id ).prop( 'checked', true );

// Or, select it by click.
$( id ).trigger( 'click' );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  1
  <input type="radio" id="1">
</label>

<label>
  2
  <input type="radio" id="2">
</label>

<label>
  3
  <input type="radio" id="3">
</label>
```